# Complex Polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this question on a practice final,

Find all the solutions to the equation $$2z^2 = √2 − i√2$$

I'm not quite sure how to solve this! Should I approach this with synthetic division? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers) helps in cases to solve $z^n=a$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt2 - i\sqrt2 = \sqrt2(1-i)= 2\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-\dfrac{i}{\sqrt2}\right)= 2e^{-i\pi/4}$. Hence, we have
$$z^2 = e^{2n\pi i-i\pi/4} \implies z = e^{(n-1/8)\pi i}$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This gives only two distinct solutions though, namely, $z = e^{-i\pi/8},e^{7\pi i/8}$

Answer (score 0):

$$2z^2 = \sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}<=>$$
$$z^2=\frac{\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}}{2}<=>$$
$$z^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}<=>$$
$$z^2=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right|e^{arg\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)i}<=>$$
$$z^2=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2}e^{arg\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)i}<=>$$
$$z^2=e^{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\pi +2\pi k\right)i}<=>$$
$$z=\left(e^{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\pi +2\pi k\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<=>$$
$$z=e^{\left(-\frac{1}{8}\pi +\pi k\right)i}$$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

(with k goes from 0 to 1 -> k=0-1)